# Request timer interrupts in userspace program?

Tags: c, time, interrupt

Is it possible (preferably in an OS-independent fashion, although I happen to be using Windows) to request a timer interrupt in a userspace program?

Here is some pseudo-code which may illustrate what kind of functionality I'm looking for:

```
#include <time_library_x.h> //For setHandler() and set_timer_for_ms()

void timerInterruptHandler() {
    update_something();
    set_timer_for_ms(50);
}

void main() {
    setHandler(timerInterruptHandler);
    set_timer_for_ms(50);

    while(1) {
        very_boring_data_collection();
    }
}
```

Anyone know what "library x" is?

Comment: Asynchronous timers are about as portable as a ten ton rock.  `#include <windows.h>`, use CreateTimerQueueTimer().

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, there is [Timers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632592(v=vs.85).aspx) object to create Timer object and register callback function.

In Linux using SIGALRM and [setitimer](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setitimer) is common to implement timer things, but I have not seen such libraries which integrates those for mult-platform use.

Windows Timers Example : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644901(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Linux has timer_create for this purpose. Signals is one way, but thread based timers are supported as well. All timers must have os support. Interrupts are only accessible to the os and shared among multiple programs. So you can not register your own handlers from process space. But you can subscribe to a signal that will get delivered to your process when an interrupt occurs. This does require os support though.